# migration to TFS 2008, build no longer moves resource dlls to bin folder

Tags: msbuild

We recently moved our source control from 2005 to 2008 and the web projects builds have stopped copying the resource dlls for referenced (project reference) resx files into the bin folder (they remain at the same level as _publishedWebsites). I cannot see anything different in the build (It is still set to Mixed Platforms) but at the _CopyWebApplication target the copy ignores these folders, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like we had a problem with the targets file for webapplications, I copied over the old one and the builds worked. doesn't exactly answer the why but it got us working. If I get a chance to diff them I will and post the result

Answer (score 0):

If you get a chance, post your answer, as I've recently run into the same issue.  The referenced project .dlls are not being placed in the _PublishedWebsites folder, but are being placed at the same level.